# could an app over-clock an ipod if it needed to?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, ipod-touch

I was just wondering could ipod app use more cpu than the 600mhz (3rd gen) under-clocked speed if it needed to?

Because I would like to make an *Intense* 3d game with [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) only using HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript, and i calculated it would need to use more than the under-clocked speed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Enough said, but SO forces me to write more x(

If you want intense 3D, go native. You won't achieve something "intense" with eg. phonegap.